# Ember Handlebars template does not work after it initially loads

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I recently went from ember rc8 to 1.0.0 and to ember-data beta-2. When I did this, there were several error messages but this one I cannot figure out:

`Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.`

I am currently in the process of getting into a jsbin to debug but in the meantime I created this album to demonstrate what is going on : [Album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeXS9.jpg)

Here is the Route when the error is displayed:

```
App.BadgeBasicRoute = Ember.Route.extend({  
model: function(params) {
       return this.modelFor('badge');
    }   
})
```

and its parent route:

```
App.BadgeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

   model: function(params) {
      return this.store.find('badge',params.badge_id); 
   },
   afterModel: function(params) {
      return this.transitionTo('badge.basic', params)
   }

});
```

and here are the templates:

**BadgeBasic.hbs**

```
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col col-lg-12">
              <h3>Basic Info</h3>
             <hr>
             <div class="row page-header-title">
                 <div class="col col-lg-11">
                     <h4>Tag Line</h4>
                 </div>
                 {{! test comment }}
                 {{#view App.EditTagLineView}}
                     <h4 {{bindAttr class=":glyphicon isEditingTagLine:glyphicon-nothing:glyphicon-pencil :edit-button"}}></h4>
                 {{/view}}
             </div>
             <p>
                 {{#if isEditingTagLine}}         

                     {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="short_description" class="form-control" style="padding-top:10px"}}
                     <hr>
                     <button {{action saveTagLine}} class="btn btn-success">Save</button>         

                 {{else}}         

                     {{#if short_description}}         

                         {{short_description}}         

                     {{else}}         

                         No tag line provided         

                     {{/if}}         

                 {{/if}}
             </p>
             <div class="row page-header-title">
             <div class="col col-lg-11">
                 <h4>
                     Description
                 </h4>
             </div>
                 {{#view App.EditDescriptionView}}
                     <h4 {{bindAttr class=":glyphicon isEditingDescription:glyphicon-nothing:glyphicon-pencil :edit-button"}}></h4>
                 {{/view}}
             </div>
             <p>
                 {{#if isEditingDescription}}
                     {{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="full_description" class="form-control" rows="6"}}
                     <hr>
                     <button {{action saveDescription}} class="btn btn-success">Save</button> 
                     <a href="http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax" target="new" class="btn btn-link"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> More on Markdown </a>
                 {{else}}
                     {{#if full_description}}
                         {{markdown full_description}}
                     {{else}}
                         <span class="text-muted">no description provided</span>
                     {{/if}}
                 {{/if}}
                 </p>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row page-header-title" >
         <div class="col col-lg-11">
             <h4>
                 Mentor
             </h4>
         </div>
         <div class="col col-lg-1">
         <h4 class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil edit-button"></h4>
         </div>
     </div>
             {{#if mentor}}
             <address>
                 {{log mentor}}
                 <strong> {{mentor.employee_preferred_name}}</strong>
                 <br>
                 {{#if mentor.phone}}
                 <abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> {{mentor.phone}} <br>
                 {{else}}
                 <small> no phone number provided </small> <br>
                 {{/if}}
                 {{#if mentor.email}}
                 <abbr title="Email">E:</abbr> {{mentor.email}}
                 {{else}}
                 <small> no email number provided </small> <br>
                 {{/if}}
             </address>         

             {{/if}}
     </div>
```

**Category.hbs**

```
    <div class="col col-lg-3 menu2">
        <ul style="">
            <li class="menu2-header">
                <button style="background:#5E9EF3;border:none" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">New</button>
            </li>
            {{#each badge in badges}}
                {{#link-to "badge" badge tagName="li"}}
                    <h6 style="">
                        {{badge.type}}
                    </h6>
                    <h4 style="">
                        <strong>{{badge.title}}</strong>
                    </h4>
                    <p>
                        {{badge.short_description}}
                    </p>
            {{/link-to}}
            {{else}}        

                    <p class="lead text-center" style="margin-top:2em">
                        No Badges in {{label}}
                    </p>        

            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-lg-7">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
```

**Categories.hbs**

```
    <div class="col col-lg-2 menu1">
        <ul>
            {{#each category in model}}
                    {{#if category.parent}}

                    {{else}}
                        <li class="menu1-header" > {{category.label}}  </li>
                        {{#if category.children}}
                            {{#each child in category.children}}
                                {{#link-to 'category' child tagName="li"}}
                                    {{child.label}} 
                                {{/link-to}}
                            {{/each}}
                        {{/if}}
                    {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
```

Let me know if you need any other information. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding the **badgeBasic.hbs** file and it turns out there were unmatched html tags. I do not know why this fixed it but it did.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a time or two in the past and it's almost always been due to wrapping some handlebars directive in regular html comments.  Something like:

```
<!--
{{#if something}}hey!{{else}}ho!{{/if}}
-->
```

Comment: I am going to have to add a bit more to my question I think because I do not have any html comments that I can find. Thank you though

Comment: No problem, sorry my suggestion wasn't any help.